# How to get the text in <script>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A while ago I used the following code to get `window._sharedData;` but the same code just now has no way, what should I do

If I change `script` to `div` it can work but I need is use `script`

code.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html1 = '<h1><script>window._sharedData;</script></h1>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html1)
print(soup.find('script').text)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the behavior, the code you have given outputs `window._sharedData;`

Comment: You might get a warning ``No parser was explicitly specified`` since you have not defined a parser, apart from that your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `html.parser` or `lxml` and call `.string` instead `.text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<h1><script>window._sharedData;</script></h1>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('script').string)
```

Comment: But why need to use `.string` instead of `.text`, if I use `<div>` instead of `<script>` and use `.text` it can work

Comment: @pcymichael in my case with `.text` output is empty

Comment: I use `.string` is ok but `.text` is empty, really strange

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')` instead of `BeautifulSoup(html1)`. If Output is empty, you will use `.string` instead of `.text`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html1 = '<h1><script>window._sharedData;</script></h1>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('script').text)
```

or

```
print(soup.find('script').string)
```

Output will be:

```
window._sharedData;
```

Comment: Output is empty

Comment: I check it now, I get the output `window._sharedData;`.

Comment: My case, output empty with `.text`. If `.string` is ok.

Comment: My case, Output is Ok both of them `.text` and  `.string`.